# Java FX menu ActionListener

Tags: java, events, actionlistener, fxml

since two days I'm looking for solution for my problem.

I have default menu made in fxml file:

```
<MenuBar>
    <menus>
      <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
        <items>
          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
        </items>
      </Menu>
      <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
        <items>
          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
        </items>
      </Menu>
      <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
        <items>
          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
        </items>
      </Menu>
    </menus>
  </MenuBar>
```

But for now I have no idea how many items will have the menu in future.

I need to set an ActionListener for example and get clicked menu item text.

Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

**First approach :**

```
<MenuBar>
    <menus>
      <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
        <items>
          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#actionHandler" text="Close" />
        </items>
      </Menu>
    </menus>
</MenuBar>
```

You have to use  **onAction="#actionHandler"** param, and init this in your controller class like a method:

```
@FXML
private void actionHandler(ActionEvent event) {

//action....

}
```

**Second approach :**

```
      <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
        <items>
          <MenuItem fx:id="menuItem" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
        </items>
      </Menu>
```

Set **id="menuItem"** into fxml element, then init element(Node) use **fx:id** in your controller class like a field and use **.setOnAction** or **.addEventHandler + Type of ActionEvent** to add handler :

```
@FXML
private MenuItem menuItem;

public void initMenuAction(){
    menuItem.setOnAction(action -> {
      // action ...
    });

    menuItem.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION,action ->{ 
      // action ...
    });

}
```

I would recomend to use [JavaFX scene builder 2.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-info-2157684.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I understand that method but fx:id should be unique or can I use the same?

Comment: You can use the same method in one controller scope, but ones will do same. Each controller has own scope of variables and methods which bind to fx:id's. -> see update///

Comment: You can use only one setOnAction() method (next setOnAction will override previous), and many EventsHandlers with same or different EventTypes.

Answer (score 0):

> Thank you very much for your help! I understand that method but fx:id should be unique or can I use the same?

You can use the same method in one controller scope, but ones will do same.
Each controller has own scope of variables and methods which bind to **fx:id**'s.

```
<Button fx:id="button1" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#button1" />
<Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#button1" />

@FXML
public void button1(ActionEvent e){
   System.out.println( e.getSource() +" = source ");
}
```

**Print** :

```
Button[id=button1, styleClass=button]'Button1' = source 
Button@5adbbf54[styleClass=button]'Button' = source
```